# WPF DependencyProperty always null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I'm trying to make a string property on a user control that can be defined in XAML without binding. My goal is for something like Name or any other property you can just directly enter yourself.

My user control, MediaStreamSource, has an ObservableCollection of my StreamResource class named Streams. I add its contents in XAML like so:

```
<local:MediaStreamSource Name="mediaSource">
    <local:MediaStreamSource.Streams>
         <local:StreamResource ResourceName="wildlife.wmv" ResourceLocation="includes.wildlife.wmv"/>
         <local:StreamResource ResourceName="Yami_no_Prologue.mp3" ResourceLocation="includes.Yami_no_Prologue.mp3"/>
    </local:MediaStreamSource.Streams>
</local:MediaStreamSource>
```

In the MediaStreamSource control, I also am registered for the CollectionChanged event on the Streams property. The following is the relevant parts of the MediaStreamSource class:

```
public class MediaStreamSource : UserControl
{        
    MediaStream streamer;

    public MediaStreamSource()
    {
        Streams = new ObservableCollection<StreamResource>();
        Streams.CollectionChanged += Streams_CollectionChanged;

        streamer = new MediaStream();
    }

    private void Streams_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (StreamResource resource in e.NewItems)
                streamer.RegisterFile(resource.ResourceName, resource.ResourceLocation);
        }
        else if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (StreamResource resource in e.OldItems)
                streamer.UnregisterFile(resource.ResourceName);
        }
        else if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            foreach (StreamResource resource in e.OldItems)
                streamer.UnregisterFile(resource.ResourceName);

            foreach (StreamResource resource in e.NewItems)
                streamer.RegisterFile(resource.ResourceName, resource.ResourceLocation);
        }
        else if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            streamer.UnregisterAllFiles();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<StreamResource> Streams { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that, no matter what I seem to try, the values for both properties (ResourceName and ResourceLocation in StreamResource) are always null. It happens anywhere I check the values, including the CollectionChanged callback above where I use them.

Here's the StreamResource class in question:

```
public class StreamResource : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ResourceName", typeof(string), typeof(StreamResource), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceLocationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ResourceLocation", typeof(string), typeof(StreamResource), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string ResourceName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ResourceNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResourceNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public string ResourceLocation
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ResourceLocationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResourceLocationProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I've also tried INotifyPropertyChanged but that didn't work and has been confirmed as the wrong approach.

Update: If I do the following it works just fine. It only is null for items added through XAML.

```
mediaSource.Streams.Add(new StreamResource()
{
    ResourceName = "Test.wmv",
    ResourceLocation = "includes.Wildlife.wmv"
});
```

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Matt

Comment: Consider when you check the values (in the get accessor of `ResourceStreamFile`), the code also looks fine to me. It seem to just  depend on how you check it.

Comment: Sadly I'm not following... By the way, I moved the part in the get accessor for ResourceStreamFile to the class that uses it instead and it is still null. I changed the code above to reflect those changes.

Comment: The DPs are declared correctly. (The `INotifyPropertyChanged` mechanisms won't work the way you have them written in your "second try" example, by the way. That is, they'll work and fire an event, but the code there is more like a ViewModel than a UserControl with XAML DPs.)

Comment: It might help also to see how the `Streams` DP in your `MediaStreamsSource` is declared.

Comment: @RobPerkins - Thanks for the insight. I didn't think INotifyPropertyChanged was the way to go but I was desperate. (lol)

I updated the code above to show the relevant parts of the MediaSourceStream class.